# Hanging promise in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a Node.js CLI application that dynamically imports chokidar (depending of the flags passed), and executes a function that returns a `Promise`:

```js
// index.ts
options.watch
  ? import('chokidar').then(({ default: chokidar }) =>
      chokidar
        .watch(options.watch)
        .on('ready', async () => watchAndBuild(options))
        .on('change', async () => watchAndBuild(options))
    )
  : watchAndBuild(options)
```

The `Promise` returned by `watchAndBuild` is the following

```js
// watchAndBuild.ts
return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (options.run) {
    rl.pause()
    const commandToRun = typeof options.run === 'string' ? options.run : `node ${outdir}`
    const [commandName] = commandToRun.split(' ')
    const commandParameters = commandToRun.split(' ').slice(1)
    child = spawn(commandName, commandParameters, { stdio: 'inherit' })
    child.on('close', () => {
      rl.resume()
      options.watch ? resolve() : process.exit()
    })
  } else {
    console.log(
      `${options.entry || options._.join(', ')} built successfully on ${options.outdir}`
    )
    resolve()
  }
})
```

It's expected that when both `--watch` and `--run` flags aren't passed, the code executes it task, logs the success message, resolves the promise and naturally exits the process (without needing to `process.exit()`), but instead, it hangs right on the `resolve()`, any clue of what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Chokidar uses something like a setTimeout or setInterval loop in the background, so like a server, it won't exit unless `process.exit (69)` or something is called.  My guess is the process isn't actually exiting/closing.

Comment: But what if `--watch` flag is not passed, consequently, chokidar is not imported, what could be causing this hanging behavior just by executing `watchAndBuild()` without chokidar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Somehow the problem was related to some issue in `libuv`, patched in node `>=14.6.0`, the solution was as simple as upgrading node version, [more details here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31762)

And also, i had forgotten to close a readline interface created before the `Promise`, putting a `rl.close()` right before the `resolve()` fixed it

```js
// watchAndBuild.ts
import readline from 'readline'

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

const watchAndBuild = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    if (options.run) {
      rl.pause()
      const commandToRun = typeof options.run === 'string' ? options.run : `node ${outdir}`
      const [commandName] = commandToRun.split(' ')
      const commandParameters = commandToRun.split(' ').slice(1)
      child = spawn(commandName, commandParameters, { stdio: 'inherit' })
      child.on('close', () => {
        rl.resume()
        options.watch ? resolve() : process.exit()
      })
    } else {
      console.log(
        `${options.entry || options._.join(', ')} built successfully on ${options.outdir}`
      )
      rl.close() // <--- Closes the previously declared readline interface
      resolve()
    }
  })

export default watchAndBuild
```